# Java xml file read

Tags: java, xml

Creating an xml file in my Package and the XML file content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
<sub>
<Key>TL</Key>
<value>Title</value>
</sub>
<sub>
<Key>DKN</Key>
<value>Docket No.</value>
</sub>
</main>
```

from the main class, i have declare a String Variable and passing the Following query

```
String query = "prabu<in>TL";
```

adove string Key is `TL` so now i want to read the XML file, with corresponding Key with Value and assign the value into an another string variable

```
String fieldName ="Title";
```

Can anyone please provide a suggestion how I can read the value from the xml file

Comment: Not very clear what you want - show us what you've tried please.

Comment: @Elemental : i have updated my doubts thanks

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are tying to do. Are you trying to get the content of `value` based on the content of `key`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did not simplify your XML, [java XML properties](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072602/java-properties-in-xml.html) would be an already existing solution.

The XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="TL">Title</entry>
    <entry key="DKN">Docket No.</entry>
</properties>
```

And Properties are handled as:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.loadFromXML(inputStream);

String key = "TL";
String defaultValue = "";
String value = properties.getProperty(key, defaultValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, for the  concept, but the loading the xml file not wokring for me, i have posted with seperate question

Comment: my question url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345286/error-in-properties-loadfromxmlinputstream-convert-xml-file-into-property-fi