# Error in properties.loadFromXML(inputStream) - convert xml file into property file Java

Tags: java, xml

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="TL">Title</entry>
    <entry key="DKN">Docket No.</entry>
</properties>
```

Now i convert the above xml into property format, below are the code

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("d:/fieldcode.xml");
//load the xml file into properties format
properties.loadFromXML(inputStream);
String key = "TL";
String defaultValue = "";
String value = properties.getProperty(key, defaultValue);
```

Below line shown an error

```
properties.loadFromXML(inputStream);
```

Error description

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    - Syntax error on token "inputStream", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
```

let me know what was the problem in that line

Comment: Your code is working fine. I think you are getting some syntax error in your code and the code you post are altered and not original which is causing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file location is at the root directory of `D:`.

If you want the file to be of read-only character, integrated in your application, use a resource instead of a file system File. Resources like .class are packed in the application's jar.

Depending of the build infrastructure, it must be in some source folder, like src/fieldcode.xml, and gotten as:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fieldcode.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your code in my environment. It is working fine.(without any exceptions)
Got the value as Title.
I think you should re check your xml file location and the project location.

Comment: xml file located in inside the Package under the same project

Comment: is that so.. as @Naveen said, did you re check the code? is it same as in here?